# Why do you have to have an anonymous function in addeventlistener when passing parameters?

Tags: javascript

So if you have a named function with parameters and call that function, it doesn't work properly when using the addEventListener, but if you wrap that in an anonymous function, then it works, why is that?

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="subBtn" /> <br />
<div id="myDiv">default text</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript.

```
function myFunc(str){
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = str;
}

//does not work.
document.getElementById("subBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunc("hey there buddy"), false);

//this works, but why?
document.getElementById("subBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
   myFunc("hey there buddy");
}, false);
```

Now if myFunc didn't take any parameters, then both ways would work.

Comment: the second parameter is a reference to a function, in your second example you are firing the function directly. `addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);` would work, the trick is passing a parameter through it.

Comment: To add to the comment above, you are executing `myFunc()` and passing the *result* of that function (`undefined`) to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this works:

```
function(){
   //code here
  }
```

Is that is a function declaration, which doesn't get fired until the click event occurs. This is the same:

```
var foo = function(){
  //code here
};

element.addEventListener('click', foo, false);
```

However now you have the problem of not having a parameter because they are only pasted when you are actually firing the function. That action is buried inside of the `addEventListener`, and isn't reachable directly.

That being said, there is a simple workaround using `.bind`:

```
element.addEventListener('click', myFunc.bind(null, 'Hey there buddy'), false);
```

What bind does is creates a function that has a bound scope (first argument, which can be quite useful) and parameters ( every argument after ).

This effectively passes a bound parameter to your named function, without an anonymous wrapper.

Comment: You know, if I had parameters, I would just use an anonymous function to fire it off, I just never knew why you had to do that or have to have a another function, its always nice when you understand why, instead of just doing it, because you know it works. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @dragonore I'm glad I was able to add clarity! As a side note: `.bind` is an exceptionally powerful and useful part of javascript, if you're not familiar with it it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a function as an argument to `addEventListener`.

However, it doesn't have to be anonymous:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function IAmNotAnonymous(){
   myFunc("hey there buddy");
});
```

And you can use function call, without a function expression wrapper. However, the value returned in that call must be a function:

```
function myFunc2(arg) {
    return someFunction; // <-- This must be a function
}
element.addEventListener("click", myFunc2("hey there buddy"));
```

When you use `addEventListener("click", myFunc("hey there buddy"))`, it doesn't work because your `myFunc` doesn't return a function. Instead,

- You are calling `myFunc`, without waiting for the event
- You are passing the returned value (`undefined`) as the argument to `addEventListener`

Note that this problem is not due to having arguments, it's due to calling the function. Using `addEventListener("click", myFunc())` would be the same.

Instead of using a function expression wrapper, you may be interested in [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
element.addEventListener("click", myFunc.bind(void 0, "hey there buddy"));
```